# Vue.js block repeat table rows doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html-table, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I would like to repeat adding table rows using a template tag with vue.js, but it doesn't work in IE11. Here is the code.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">ID</td>
    <td colspan="2">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Height</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
  </tr>
<template v-repeat="items">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">{{id}}</td>
    <td colspan="2">{{name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{height}}</td>
    <td>{{weight}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
</table>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

See http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Using_Components and the warning at the end of that section:

> The table element has restrictions on what elements can appear inside
>   it, so custom elements will be hoisted out and not render properly. In
>   those cases you can use the component directive syntax:
>
> `<tr v-component="my-component"></tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that changed the `<template>` tag to a `<tbody>` tag. However there would be multiple `<tbody>` tags in a table, I hope this is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make a long story short, This is HTML restrictions in IE, if you want compatibility, you will have to change your HTML structure.

I found an issue with similar question like yours here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2404

> Vue renders the template into real html before compiling it, so the same html restrictions apply for Vue templates, no matter how you define it.
>
> IE does not support  inside elements like , ..